# Push notification opens always MainActiviy

Tags: android, push-notification

i have created a cloud function which sends data with the notifications. Now i want to open always the specific activity. Unfortunately its opening always the MainActivity. Here is my Code of my Firebase Service:

```
   @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Map<String, String> dataSet = remoteMessage.getData();
    if (!dataSet.get("kind").equals("0")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.baseline_send_24)
                        .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
                        .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"))
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.


        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }else{
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.baseline_send_24)
                        .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
                        .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"))
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.


        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }


}
```

I dont know if i have to define it somewhere else. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction("ACTION.HOME_ACTION");
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

and set this pendingintent in notification

`.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)`

Answer (score 0):

Incase you are using Firebase for your push notifications. If you use the 'notification' type payload, while sending from server, Firebase manages the display of notification for your app without giving a callback and by default will always open the launcher activity of your app.

You can send extra data from the server side, access that data in your launcher activity getIntent methods and redirect to some other activity as needed